# Can you bake or grill well done lamb chops that are also soft?

Tags: meat, texture, lamb

I bought some grilled lamb chops from the shop and they were soft, juicy and medium rare.

I reheated them and quite quickly the outside browned and went crusty and the inside got cooked.  The result was tougher meat with a not soft surface.

Is it possible to have soft, tender lam chops by grilling or baking while having it well done too?

Comment: Not from a supermarket.

Answer (score 3):

No, you absolutely cannot. "Well done" is primarily a description of texture, and that texture is not soft and juicy. When you bake meat (or any other protein), it goes through many different stages, depending on the temperature, and you stop when you have reached the desired texture. If you stop at the texture of "well done", you can never return back to the soft texture of "medium rare".